# What is the easiest way to install libgdal 3.3.0 and header files (gdal-devel) on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python, gdal, installation, pip

I would like to pip install [GDAL 3.3.0](https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/3.3.0/) Python package, but it requires libgdal (3.3.0 or greater) and header files (gdal-devel). APT package manager repositories only have gdal-bin 2.4.2 and libgdal-dev 2.4.2.

Is there any other way to install libgdal 3.3.0 than from source?

If installing from source is the only option, is there any step-by-step guide for that? I once tried it by installing sqlite3 which was required by PROJ 6 and then PROJ 6 which was required by GDAL and still got `configure: error: PROJ 6 symbols not found` error. I guess I didn't just understand something.

Comment: Sorry for misleading answer (deleted as support in Conda at the moment was for GDAL 3.2.2, no GDAL 3.3) For install from source, see CI code e.g https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/.github/workflows/ubuntu_18.04/install.sh. Question: why do you need the 3.3 version? 3.2.2 not enough? It's not like you can't install older Python GDAL e.g https://pypi.org/project/GDAL/#history